# Installation bug in mysql-server-5.6 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to remove mysql-workbench. But every time when I try to remove something related with mysql, I get this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
mysql-server-5.6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 52,5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 309141 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.24-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postrm: line 53: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Help, please!

Comment: I already tryied something like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82295/error-uninstalling-postgresql-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code), but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1455818

#### Workaround:

Open post installation script on `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst` and comment out line 95:

```
### /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks install mysql "$mysql_cfgdir/mysql.cnf"
```

Retry installation.

Comment: After commenting out this line, I receive additional errors when attempting to reinstall. `2017-12-13T00:27:37.441194Z 0 [ERROR] You have enabled the binary log, but you haven't provided the mandatory server-id. Please refer to the proper server start-up parameters documentation
`