# MySql Installation problem in dual boot ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql

I am getting an `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` error when installing mysql 5.6 in Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

I have tried to modified

> /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst and comment out line 95:
>
> /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks install mysql  "$mysql_cfgdir/mysql.cnf"

but i did not find the

> /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks install mysql  "$mysql_cfgdir/mysql.cnf" line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does someone knows how to fix this installation bug in ubuntu?mysql-server-5.6 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643667/does-someone-knows-how-to-fix-this-installation-bug-in-ubuntumysql-server-5-6-e)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall it using the cmd on terminal 
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.6
then 
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6

Comment: done more than one time,
No improvement