# MySql installation error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mysql

I have followed all these links:

[E: Mysql-server-5.5 Installation Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384234/e-mysql-server-5-5-installation-error)

[MySql Installation problem in dual boot ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754311/mysql-installation-problem-in-dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04)

https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-mysql-server-depends-on-mysql-server-5-5-however-package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet/

but I keep on getting the following error while installing mysql on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
```

output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google, Inc.,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-danielrichter2007-grub-customizer,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Launchpad PPA for Grub Customizer,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-danielrichter2007-grub-customizer,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Launchpad PPA for Grub Customizer,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin be.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5`

```
mysql-server-5.5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server`:

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What is the output of the command `apt-cache policy`?

Comment: Edited my post with the output.

Comment: Remove mysql server 5.5 with `sudo dpkg -r mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server`. Then do `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update`. Then again try to install mysql using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Gives the same problem.

Comment: Edit the question giving the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5` and `apt-cache policy mysql-server`

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45050/discussion-between-anwar-and-milan).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

For more detailed solution, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489815/cannot-install-mysql-server-5-5-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependicies)

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: basically you'll have to remove mysql-server and mysql-core-5.6(if installed) before you perform a clean install of mysql-client-core-5.5. So try removing mysql-server first using `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server` and then try the above steps. Don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` after removing the mysql-server

Comment: Same error message as I commented. Even if I sudo apt-get purge mysql* the problem persists.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is! Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, this will resolve the broken packages.

Comment: That is where the error comes from so it gives the same error.